# iOS - Received memory warning

Tags: ios, avaudioplayer, mpmovieplayer, didreceivememorywarning, memory-warning

The app plays video n audio from the bundle. When I'm testing the app on my iPod Touch, SOMETIMES just before the video is getting played, it logs the message. sometimes when the app wants to prepare the audioplayer (in another viewController) it logs the message.

However I haven't had a crash YET! :D I'm not sure if there's gonna be a crash if it runs on other devices which have multiple apps open.
So, should I worry about this? should I prepareAudioPlayer or moviePlayer in another thread?
or just ignore it?

Answer (score 2):

Even if you prepare it on other threads it will not solve this issue, what you have to do is to prepare your self for when you recieve a memory warning to act upon it and free some memory that you dont need

Try to free some memory up, optimize your application memory consumption, using lazy loading technique and so on, but using another thread is definitely not a solution

Comment: I don't think I can free up memory; cuz I'm using ARC (automatic reference counting)
and there's not much of lazy instantiation I can do. will it cause a crash?

Comment: you can by setting the strong properties to nil. for example if you have an array that is strong, you can use self.array = nil